# Query to Find Double-Header

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for scheduling of sports.  I'd like to be able to find when a double-header has been scheduled.  That is, two games for the same team on the same day.  Here's a sample table:

```
id      event           start_date          end_date            homeid awayid
3391    team1 vs. team2 2016-04-27 17:00:00 2016-04-27 18:00:00 3      1
3395    team2 vs. team3 2016-04-27 17:00:00 2016-04-27 18:00:00 5      3
3396    team1 vs. team3 2016-05-04 17:00:00 2016-05-04 18:00:00 5      1
3392    team3 vs. team2 2016-05-04 19:40:00 2016-05-04 20:40:00 3      5
3393    team3 vs. team1 2016-05-11 17:55:00 2016-05-11 18:55:00 1      5
3394    team2 vs. team1 2016-05-18 17:55:00 2016-05-18 18:55:00 1      3
```

I'm able to find the days of the double-headers with something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%j')
```

But, what I need help with is determining which team, using the teamids which are set in the homeid and awayid columns, has the double-header on those days.  For example, I need to know on 4/27 the team with id of '3' has the double header.  On 5/4 it's teamid of '5'.

I'm sure the answer is simple but I'm struggling with it today.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky.  One way uses `union all` and `group by`:

```
select team, day, count(*) as numgames
from ((select id, homeid as team, date(start_date) as day
       from t
      ) union all
      (select id, awayid as team, date(start_date)
       from t
      )
     ) t
group by team, day
having numgames > 1;
```

Comment: I was trying to think how to do it with a single pass of the table. This will suffice. :)

Comment: This is perfect!  Thanks!